# How to change IIS domain name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-webpages

I have an asp.net web forms application and I have different result concerning domain name. When I'm debugging my app - for default my domain zone is ".com".  But I want to test it with another domain name and trying to find out how.

I'm hosting on IIS.
 I tried to change locale in the web.config, but this doesn't affect me. I read that I can be changed on the IIS setting of my app, but I couldn't find out where it is.

How can I change the default domain name from ".com" to ".uk" domain name?

Comment: you can set domain name in iis like this:https://templatetoaster.com/tutorials/iis-set-domain-name/

Comment: Spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

In the IIS management console, you can edit the bindings to a domain. 
Rightclick on your website and select "Edit bindings"

[image: IIS Management]

Comment: i'm trying to test it on localhost and typed " *.uk " in Host name. Now i can't run debug, because i have an error  "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server returned error 404"

Comment: When you bind your application to a domain, IIS is expecting the domain in the HTTP request.